# Perforce - Generate patch after sync

Tags: perforce, synchronization, patch

I would like to reserve a 'snapshot' after Perforce sync. Rather than applying sync to all directory tree, I would like to generate a patch file. I will apply manually and checking if the result (after compiling and running simple test cases) satisfies. I am going to do sync officially if result is OK. If it is NG, I can revert to previous 'snapshot' and continue without hard steps of rolling-back.

I can rely on 'patch' since it supports 'undo'. Telling perforce not to sync but to generate patch, how can I do that?

I appreciate if you can guide me how to automate via script. The steps on p4v is OK.

Regards,
Toan Le

Comment: What's wrong with using the actual sync mechanism? As long as you know what changelist you are at before syncing to the new changelist, it's trival to sync back if something goes wrong. This seems like reinventing the wheel...

Comment: I agree with Mike, you're making this more difficult than it has to be.  What do you mean by "hard steps of rolling-back"?  It couldn't be simpler.  Just right click on the submitted changelist and use the "Back Out Submitted Changelist" item.  Also, why are you submitting code *before* you've tested "if result is OK"?

Comment: Oops, my information might not be enough. My co-workers and I modify the same project. Unfortunately, admin does not configure private space for us to do branching. Therefore, all we submit will reside on main-stream. Sometimes, syncing from others make my project crash so I think of using patch. Of-course, I can maintain 2 workspaces but it is waste of resources. What I would like to do is (1) generate patch from fake-sync (p4 sync -n), my workspace remains un-changed; (2) I will verify and merge by-hands to make sure result does not crash

Comment: I thought my approach is better but it turns out that the poor working procedure harms the use of good tool. Agree with Mike and raven not to try re-inventing the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

As mike and raven suggested, those are good points.

But also you can use branching strategies - make your source code into 2 branches. one for test branch and one for release branch. but here you will have to work on integration/merging as well. best would be to validate your check in perforce using any CI tools (such as hudson, curisecontrol) as part of incremental build and running all the required test cases automated.

Comment: Oops, my information might not be enough. The situation is team (I belong) modifies the same project. Unfortunately, admin does not configure private space for us to do branching. Therefore, all we submit will reside on main-stream.

Comment: maintaining two workspace is a good idea. I used it to testing release and confirming everything is OK.